# Can lftp execute a command on the downloaded files (as part of the mirroring process)?

Tags: bash, find, lftp

This may be asking too much from an already very powerful tool, but is there a chance that `lftp mirror` can execute a command during the mirroring process (from remote directory to the local machine)?

Specific example: `lftp` is asked to mirror a remote directory with `xml` files into a local folder and as soon as each file is downloaded/updated, it converts the file to JSON format using `xml2json`.

I can think of a solution that relies on monitoring the local copy of the mirrored folder for changes via `find` and then executing `xml2json` on the new/updated files, but perhaps there is a simpler way?

Comment: If you're mirroring *to* your local machine, you can probably use the `source -e` command *after* the FTP is finished to run some sort of `find ... | xargs xml2json...`.

If you're mirroring *from* your local machine to some remote machine, I suspect there's nothing you can do. LFTP is a very powerful tool, but it is fundamentally limited to what FTP can do and executing arbitrary commands on the remote machine is not one of them. http://lftp.yar.ru/ . But I think that's all implicit in your question and you want to do it in parallel as it happens, and I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question! I'm mirroring from the remote to local directory... it's a very large mirror (2+ million small files), so I want to speed up the data processing (at least on the first run).

Comment: If `lftp` uses a temporary name while the file is still incomplete, you could simply have a separate process watching for new `xml` files without a corresponding `json` companion file.  Maybe check out `inotify`.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks, `inotify` will be more efficient that re-running `find`! I can run this parallel to the mirroring script, and that's basically what I was looking for. I'm on OSX so I don't have `inotify' installed, but I'll check the alternatives/how to install (`fswatch` seems to be an alternative, will need to check).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use xfer:verify and xfer:verify-command settings to run a local command on every transferred file.